# Undefined input value in table

Tags: javascript, html-table, undefined

I am having a problem with a table I'm making with Javascript. The table itself and its functions are working quite nice, but the one thing I am struggling with is submitting the value, and making it be not "undefined". 
Provided code is below(values and functions are named in Norwegian, but I hope it is understandable nevertheless).

```
let skjema = document.getElementById("skjema");
let inpAar = document.getElementById("inpAar");
let inpPromille = document.getElementById("inpPromille");
let inpFart = document.getElementById("inpFart");
let tabell = document.getElementById("tabell");

let lovbruddene = new Map();
lovbruddene.set("2008" , { promille: 9631, fart: 9863});
lovbruddene.set("2009" , { promille: 8593, fart: 12217});
lovbruddene.set("2010" , { promille: 8363, fart: 14920});
lovbruddene.set("2011" , { promille: 8128, fart: 14929});
lovbruddene.set("2012" , { promille: 8514, fart: 15425});

function lagreData(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  if (!lovbruddene.has(inpAar.value)) {
    lovbruddene.set(inpAar.value, {})
  }
  let lovbrudd = lovbruddene.get(inpAar.value);
  lovbrudd.promille = Number(inpPromille.value);
  lovbrudd.fart = Number(inpFart.value);

  lagTabell();
}

function finnAar(){
  if (lovbruddene.has(inpAar.value)) {
    let lovbrudd = lovbruddene.get(inpAar.value);
    inpPromille.value = lovbrudd.promille;
    inpFart.value = lovbrudd.fart;
  } else {
    inpPromille = "";
    inpFart = "";
  }
}
function slett(key){
  lovbruddene.delete(key);
  lagTabell();
}
function lagTabell() {
  tabell.innerHTML = "";
  for ( let [key, lovbrudd] of lovbruddene) {
    tabell.innerHTML += `
      <tr>
        <td>${key}</td>
        <td>${lovbrudd.promille}</td>
        <td>${lovbrudd.fart}</td>
        <td>${lovbrudd.fart + lovbrudd.promille}</td>
        <td>
          <button onclick="slett('${key}')"class="button tiny">X</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    `;
  }
}
  lagTabell();
    inpAar.addEventListener("input", finnAar);
    skjema.addEventListener("submit", lagreData);
```

Comment: your variable lovbrudd is local. I dont understand. What purpose does it serves?

Comment: @AbhishekAnand singular form of «lovbruddene», if that helps.

Comment: What I meant was why did you define it and not use it. Its in the scope and is not being used anywhere else.

Comment: @AbhishekAnand i don’t know, still not good at effectivizing my code. But do you think it has something to do with the submitted values being displayed as undefined? And also, the value for years(inpAar) is working, but the other two other(inpPromille, inpFart) are showing up as undefined in the table.